# onActivityResult - using nested activities

Tags: android, android-activity, nested, onactivityresult

My question is more to discuss how to re-structure my project, or solve this situation.

I have the following schema:
**MainActivity**, with a TabHost, loading Activities for each existing tab. So for the first tab im calling/opening the **FirstTabActivity**, and this FirstTabActivity is calling another Activity (to pick some Photos) called **GalleryPickActvity**

This is waht i have:
**FirstTabActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CreateCommentsActivity.this, SelectPicturesActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("TAG", "onActivityResult");    
}
```

**GalleryPickActvity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryPickActvity.this,
                            FirstTabActivity.class);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

The method: *onActivityResult* is never called, and i guess is because im using nested activities, so the result is lost.

So i have 2 questions:

1. Even its not the best approach (activity -> activity -> activity) how could i solve this problem?
2. What is the best way to structure a situation like this? I need to keep the state in all Tabs activities, and i can do that with the activities (the way it is now).

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to open a third activity you could use just `startActivity()` with some parameters in order to know that everything was correct. Is there any special reason for you to use `onActivityResult()` in your third activity without calling `startActivityForResult(...)` from that third activity?.

Comment: the activity calling startActivityForResult() and onActivityResult() is the second activity.

Comment: then just use `setResult(Activity.Result_OK); finish();` you dont need the intent, if your are going back to the previous activity.

Comment: but the method onActivityResult() is never called.

Comment: If I get it right your second activity calls a third one using `startActivityForResult()` and that third activity is the one that uses `setResult(...)` right?. Check if you are calling to `finish()` in your second activity.